# Horizontal cline lengths inside blkarray

Tags: matrices, cline, blkarray

Consider the following MWE using the `blkarray` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{blockarray}{[ccc|ccc|cc]c}
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & 
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} \\
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & 
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} \\
& \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & 
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} \\ \cline{1-8}
&            &            & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & 
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & p \\
&            &            & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & 
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} \\
&            &            &            & \mathsf{x} & 
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} \\\cline{1-8}
&            &            &            &            & 
& \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & q \\   
&            &            &            &            & 
&            & \mathsf{x} \\   
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

where the two `\cline`s can be seen to intersect with the braces.  What is the best means of trimming these?  The `\cmidrule` command from `booktabs` does approximately this, but has a negative interaction with the two vertical lines.

Also, compared with an equivalent `bmatrix` it looks to my eye as if the braces are somewhat closer to the elements of the matrix than usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no interaction with the vertical lines if you locally remove the padding of booktabs rules, which depend on the values of `\aboverulesep` (default: `0.605mm` or `0.4ex`) and `\belowrulesep{<width>}` (default: `0.984mm` or `0.65ex`) :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}
\[ \setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
    \setlength\cmidrulewidth{0.5pt}
\begin{blockarray}{[ccc|ccc|cc]c}
\bigstrut[t]\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} &
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} \\
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} &
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} \\
& \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} &
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){1-8}
& & & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} &
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & p \\
& & & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} &
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} \\
& & & & \mathsf{x} &
\mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} \\%\cline{1-8}
\cmidrule(lr){1-8} & & & & && \mathsf{x} & \mathsf{x} & q \\
    & & & & & & & \mathsf{x}\bigstrut[b] \\
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]